# Invoking C++ functions from a REST based web service

Tags: php, c++, web-services, api, rest

I have a C++ API (back-end) and I'd like to use it as a web-service. I am thinking of using REST as an interface between the front end and the back end. I found a bunch of C++ libraries for REST, but what I ultimately want is to keep the C++ API clear/independent of the REST stuff, and handle all of that in the front end, thus keeping the C++ API general purpose and reusable. Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Also, my API is not focused on collections of data, but on processing the data that will be given as an input to the functions contained in the API. So basically, the C++ functions receive input data from the web, process it and return output data. I just need to be able to make API calls passing the input data as parameters and get output data back.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this: I'd like to keep my API implementation dependent i.e I want it to be usable/callable from any language. That is the reason I wanted to have a REST interface. Basically, the user should be able to use any language of their convenience to place calls to the functions defined in the API.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm guessing from the tags that you want a PHP server that calls C++ functions?

If so, you can call c++ routines directly from the PHP code using [PHP extensions](http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/). Alternatively, create a wrapper for your C++ code using SWIG, or put your C++ routines in a executable and call it using system() passing the parameters as standard input.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this kind of thing is using a PHP frontend talking to your C++ backend via sockets.

You'll need wrapper layers at the C++ and PHP sides to serialize/deserialize your calls. For this there is any number of solutions: you can use XML, JSON, AMF, protocol buffers, thrift, etc.

This can scale nicely as you can have multiple PHP frontends calling your C++ backend - but is only really necessary if your backend is stateful.

If the backend is not stateful then you're better off just using `system` style calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a wrapper for your API, transform your api functions into rest endpoints, and use DTOs to decouple the REST layer from your api, for this you can use otapp, a very complete rest framework in C ++.

Comment: Example: https://github.com/rquiroga83/cpp_microservice